# The edit field must have a mathematical equation alert using MATLAB GUIDE

Tags: matlab, math, field, edit, equation

I want to add a validation to the first edit field shown in the following interface:
[image: The interface]

So, if the user enters something other than a mathematical equation, an error message must appear to the user. 
How can I do such a validation, what shall I be writing exactly in the edit field call back function to do that?

```
function editEquation_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% hObject  handle to editEquation (see GCBO) 
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB 
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of editEquation as text 
% str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of editEquation as a double

if () 
    errordlg('Enter a valid mathematical equation', 'Error', 'modal');
else
    %do nothing
end
```

Comment: I imagine the only way to do that would be to use a regular expression

Comment: How do you define a "mathematical equation"? Must it be a valid MATLAB expression, or will a different syntax be used? How will the equation be used?

Comment: @Paolo How? Can you show me with an example?